# Change values in cells depending outcome

Tags: excel

I have created an interest rate model in excel that contains a stochastic part created by the NORMINV() command. However sometimes I get the error #NUM!. I would like to know how I can create a function that assigns a certain value to cells with the text #NUM! in them.

I have tried a IF function but it didnt work as it didnt see #NUM! as a logical outcome, e,g, IF(B3=#NUM!, "2").

Or perhaps I just missunderstood.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use IFERROR()

For example `IFERROR(B3;"2")`

Comment: Thank you! But how do I add the IFERROR argument to my current equation. For example in cell B4 i have now written =IFERROR(B3;"2")+Sheet1!$B$5*(Sheet1!$B$6-B3)*(Sheet1!$B13)+(B3)^0.5*(Sheet1!$B$7)*(Sheet1!D13)*(Sheet1!$B13^0.5)+B3. But what it does it that it just keeps adding 2 even though cell B3 does not have an error.

Comment: Solved it, I realized the IFERROR argument of course has to be around the whole equation such that IFERROR((EQUATION);"2"). Thank you very much!